# Accessing AWS RDS Arn from aws rds describe-db-instances

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to access some RDS clusters in my account.  I have the command working with this.

This is the input data.

```
"stdout_lines": [
            "{",
            "    \"DBInstances\": [",
            "        {",
            "            \"PubliclyAccessible\": false, ",
            "            \"MasterUsername\": \"xxxxx\", ",
            "            \"MonitoringInterval\": 0, ",
            "            \"LicenseModel\": \"general-public-license\", ",
            "            \"VpcSecurityGroups\": [",
            "                {",
            "                    \"Status\": \"active\", ",
            "                    \"VpcSecurityGroupId\": \"xxxx\"",
            "                }",
            "            ], ",
            "            \"InstanceCreateTime\": \"xxxxxx\", ",
            "            \"CopyTagsToSnapshot\": false, ",
            "            \"OptionGroupMemberships\": [",
            "                {",
            "                    \"Status\": \"in-sync\", ",
            "                    \"OptionGroupName\": \"xxxxx\"",
                         ........
            "            \"DBInstanceArn\": \"arn:aws:rds:region:xxxx:db:xxxx\", ",
                          .......
```

When running the command below targeting the [0[ item in the array I receive this output.

> "{{ (registered.stdout_lines | from_json)['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceArn'] }}"

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "arn:aws:rds:region :xxxx:db:xxxx"
}
```

I can get down to the item I need by specifying it like this. I need the array ID in there as there are 3 of them. I have tried to run it this way. But I get all the data.

```
 - name: Show
      set_fact:
         var: "item.db_instance_arn"
       with_items: "{{rds.instances}}"
       register: variable
```

I also get the fact that I want. I just cant output that individual fact.

Is there a way to hit all the items in the array and output the one variable I need?

Thanks in advance. Happy New Year!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add a sample of the input data and and example of the expected result ? Thanks.

Comment: Have updated.  Hopefully it makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: What is "rds.instances" in your loop ? What is the data in there ? What is the current result your are getting ? What is the result you expect ?

Comment: rds is my registered content and from the describe command and instances is the first value that is returned from the data.  The current result I am getting is the 3 instances in the array followed by the value I am looking for.    I would expect to just get the value I am looking for.

Comment: Can you edit your question again and add a full/valid debug (that one can copy/paste directly in a variable definition) of `rds.instances` and the exact expected output in yaml or json format ? You should also spend some time reading the help section of the site, more specifically [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want `(registered.stdout | from_json)`, not `(registered.stdout_lines | from_json) }}`, because `stdout_lines` is a `list` of `str`, but `from_json` wants a `str` -- I'm surprised your question didn't include the error message that you experienced, because it for sure produces one

Then, once you have straightened out the JSON parsing, you will want to use the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map), because as you observed, `DBInstances` is a `list`, meaning you need to effectively iterate over its objects like so:

```
- debug:
    msg: my DB ARNs are {{
       (registered.stdout | from_json).DBInstances
       | map(attribute="DBInstanceArn")
       | list }}
```

If you prefer, you can use the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) which uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org) syntax, although most of the time I find it more opaque than helpful:

```
- debug:
    msg: my DB ARNs are {{ (registered.stdout | from_json)
       | json_query('DBInstances[*].DBInstanceArn') }}
```

Comment: Thank you mdaniel!  This solved my  problem.  I was able to ues both options and get the data I needed.  Thank you so much for the help.  Now I need to register these and run tasks against each RDS instance.

Comment: So now I am trying to run this same command but I need to extract 2 variables.  I need the `DBInstanceArn` and the `CACertificateIdentifier`.  I tried to use `aws rds describe-db-instances` but this didn't work as the `CACertificateIdentifier` isnt a valid filter.    Basically I need to only target the RDS instances that are != to rds-ca-2019

Comment: Comments are not a good forum for asking new questions, nor posting code; try asking a new question about the `CACertificateIdentifier` and include the error you are experiencing when trying to access it

Comment: Thank you.  Will change that now.